# Subset equality between power sets.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

This question is from **Mathematics for Computer Science** *by Albert R. Meyer, Eric Lehman, and Frank Thomson Leighton* and about the relationship between power sets.

> Prove that 
>  $\hspace{3cm}$ $pow(A) \cup pow(B) \subseteq pow(A \cup B),$
> with equaltity holding if and only if $A $ or $B$ is a subset of the other

So, I've proved the subset equality as below: We need to show that, 
$\forall C: [C \in (pow(A) \cup pow(B)] \Rightarrow [C \in pow(A \cup B)] \:$
$\forall C$:
$[C \in (pow(A) \cup pow(B)] \Rightarrow [C \in pow(A) \cup C \in pow(B)] \Rightarrow [(C \subseteq A) \vee (C \subseteq B)] \Rightarrow [C \subseteq (A \cup B)] \Rightarrow [C \in pow(A \cup B]. \blacksquare$
I have a problem trying to show that equality is possible only when $A$ or $B$ is subset of the other. How to prove this? I would appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $pow(A) \cup pow(B) = pow(A \cup B)$ then $pow(A) \cup pow(B) \supseteq pow(A \cup B)$.

In particular $A\cup B\in pow(A \cup B)\Rightarrow A\cup B\in pow(A)\cup pow(B)\Rightarrow A\cup B\in pow(A)\lor A\cup B\in pow(B)\Rightarrow A\cup B\subseteq A\lor A\cup B\subseteq B\Rightarrow B\subseteq A\lor A\subseteq B$

Comment: How could you come up with the idea to write (a intersection b) is a member of pow(A U B)? I just wrote C instead of A U B and that's why, I couldn't get the result. And one more question: How do you get that if union of two sets is subset of another set, then either of two sets must the subset of that set.

Comment: Because $A\cup B$ is the extreme case. We had to look for subsets of $A\cup B$, which were going to be contained either in $A$ or in $B$. What's the subset of $A\cup B$ that could give us more problems if we hadn't the hypothesis? That's the biggest one: $A\cup B$, so having the hypothesis we should be able to get some strong condition in order to avoid those problems.